# Getting notified about change in state of WiFi on android device?

Tags: android, wifi

I am aiming to build a android app which record everything going on with devices WiFi adapter. For example WiFi being turned on/off, device getting connected/moving out of range of a WiFi router, etc.
My app should be able to record these events as soon as the device is turned on. Clearing the app from RECENTS should not affect the ability of the app to record these events.
I have gone through BroadcastReceiver. It gets tied to the life cycle of the app and hence will not record the events once app gets cleared from RECENTS.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    BroadcastReceiver mybroadcastReceiver;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mybroadcastReceiver = new WifiBroadcastReceiver(this);
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
        registerReceiver(mybroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
  }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(mybroadcastReceiver);
    }
}

public class WifiBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    final String TAG = "WifiBroadcastReceiver";
    final String desiredMacAddress = "02:17:1c:96:42:fa";
    Activity activity;

    WifiBroadcastReceiver(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();

        if (WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            SupplicantState state = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NEW_STATE);

            if (SupplicantState.isValidState(state) && state == SupplicantState.COMPLETED) 
                checkConnectedToDesiredWifi();
        }
    }

    /** Detect you are connected to a specific network. */
    private void checkConnectedToDesiredWifi() {
        WifiManager myWifiManager = (WifiManager)activity.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = myWifiManager.getConnectionInfo();

        if (wifiInfo != null) {
            // get current router MAC address
            String bssid = wifiInfo.getBSSID();

            if (desiredMacAddress.equals(bssid))
                Log.d(TAG, "Connected to " + bssid + " i.e., desiredMacAddress");
            else
                Log.d(TAG, "Connected to " + bssid + " not " + desiredMacAddress); 
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to run the BroadcastReceiver from a Service that doesn't depend on the lifecycle of any Activity.

1) Declare the network state permission usage in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

1) Create a Service class

```
public class WifiService extends Service {

    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // When creating the service, register a broadcast receiver
        // to listen for network state changes
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction("android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE");

        mReceiver = new WifiReceiver();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onUnbind(Intent intent) {
        // Unregister the receiver when unbinding the service
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        mReceiver = null;
        return super.onUnbind(intent);
    }
}
```

2) Create a BroadcastReceiver

```
public class WifiReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        boolean isConnected = networkInfo != null &&
                              networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();

        if (isConnected) {
            switch (networkInfo.getType()) {
                case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI:
                    // Connected via wifi
                    checkConnectedToDesiredWifi();
                    break;

                case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_ETHERNET:
                    // Connected via ethernet
                    break;

                case ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE:
                    // Connected via mobile data
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void checkConnectedToDesiredWifi() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

3) Declare the service in the manifest

```
    <service android:name=".receivers.WifiService"
             android:stopWithTask="false"
             android:enabled="true"/>
```

Comment: Will this wakes up the app even if I force close or kill the app, during network state change? @charlie

Comment: This should allow your app to be "woken" up onReceive() of an Intent in your BroadcastReceiver, even after all activities are closed. If you chose to, for example, you could start an activity onReceive.. therefore mimicking the app "waking up"